# At-least-once delivery using Akka Persistence and the Extra-Cameo pattern

Tags: akka, akka-persistence, reliable-message-delivery

I am developing an application that uses Akka, in which Actors are designed to avoid the Request-Response pattern. Using the Extra or the Cameo pattern is possible to model interactions among actors as a "stream" of messages.

The figure below summarizes the architecture of such actors.

[image: Actorbase communication model]

The Cameo pattern is implemented to handle the responses coming from `SK` actors.

Now, imagine that I want to guarantee the *at-least-once* semantic between `SF` and `SK` actors. How can I do that? The implementation of *ato* semantic using Akka persistence needs the implementation of a Request-Response Pattern between those actors.

How can I ensure an *at-least-once* semantic between actors that use a Cameo to handle responses?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jamie Allen helps me on Twitter to answer this question. The twitter conversation is [this](https://twitter.com/riccardo_cardin/status/951377874015195136).

I try to summarize the discussion what Jamie said.

> For reliable at-least-once, using Akka Cluster and Persistence to get it done is possible, but probably overkill. I say try to keep it simple. Have a GUID for the request, and send it with the request to the three SKs.
>
> In the immutable ledger scenario, you'd then occasionally sweep the ledger to get rid of dups by GUID. How consistent that data needs to be will define that.
>
> Simplicity is going to be a lot easier to maintain & avoid partial failures. You can handle idempotency on the SK side one of a few ways: either track all GUIDs when the requests are processed via an expiring cache, or store the GUIDs with the immutable updates in a ledger.

So, in this case, the better solution is to remove Akka Persistence completely and reduce the problem to good old message passing.

`SF` sends messages to `SK`s actors, the Cameo node waits for `SK`s responses. If such reactions don't arrive in a predetermined window of time, the Cameo node alerts `SF` using a timeout message. `SF` resends messages to SKs actors again.

The diagram that represents the above solution is the following.

[image: Cameo with home-made at-least-once delivery]

The message in red, marked with number 5, models the timeout message.

As Jamie said:

> I think ACK has to be the responsibility of the caller, all the way back to the sender of the original request. That’s the safest & simplest approach.

Hope it helps.